# Can't get object values in child component prop if prop is reactive

Tags: vuejs3, vuejs3-composition-api

I have a Parent component and try to pass reactive object as props:

```
<template>
    <Child :info="reactiveObject" />
</template>
<script setup>

const reactiveObject = reactive({ name: "Object", id: "443"})
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
    <div> {{ info.name }} 
</template>
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    info: Object,})
```

and i get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

if i pass full props object info into double brackets i get values in html like
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBBdl.png)

Why i cant get name throught info.name?

Answer (score 1):

you should import reactive from vue when you ues reactive.This is the vue3 feature. When you need to use something in vue, you must import it first.

```
import { reactive } from 'vue'
const reactiveObject = reactive({ name: "Object", id: "443"})
```

when you forget to import from vue, you cannot use it in template. This is incorrect syntax.

you should read more vue document, [this is link](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html)

Comment: i have imported reactive properly, just didnt show it for brevity

Answer (score 0):

instead of {{ info.name }} try {{ props.info.name }}, also the  there is missing the end tag

Comment: Thanks, it works. But i didn't catch at all why props.info.name is seen , info is seen and info.name undefined. Can you help me to understand this?

Comment: I always check the official vue doc: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html I think they explained well.

Comment: @MikitaZayac, if Domroe's answer helped you please consider marking it as useful or accepting it - give some brownie points!